# What role does たん play in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, manga, sentence

[image]

To me, the sentence roughly means "You see a familiar face or something?", and I'm pretty sure of it. I just don't get what the たん here is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Kansai dialect.

When translated into standard Japanese, it becomes, "知ってる顔にでも会ったのか？".

会うた + んか = 会った + のか?